# How do i draw sprite on fixture position?

Tags: c++, box2d

```
b2BodyDef bd;
    bd.position.Set(1700 / sfdd::SCALE, 150 / sfdd::SCALE);
    bd.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    b2PolygonShape squareShape;
    squareShape.SetAsBox(70 / sfdd::SCALE, 13 / sfdd::SCALE);
    m_body1 = m_world->CreateBody(&bd);
    m_body1->CreateFixture(&squareShape, 100);
    squareShape.SetAsBox(38 / sfdd::SCALE, 16 / sfdd::SCALE,b2Vec2(-54/sfdd::SCALE,-30/sfdd::SCALE),90*DEGTORAD);
    m_body1->CreateFixture(&squareShape, 20);

    squareShape.SetAsBox(30 / sfdd::SCALE, 10 / sfdd::SCALE, b2Vec2(60 / sfdd::SCALE, -20 / sfdd::SCALE), 90 * DEGTORAD);
    m_body1->CreateFixture(&squareShape, 100);
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: i tried to mess with b2Transform class. Getting shapes from a fixture but no luck. Manual of box2d doesnt even have info about b2Transform class.

Comment: Typically, if you know the size and the offsets of your fixtures, you'll know how to offset the sprites attached to it, using the same offsets as you used for the fixtures.

Comment: Yes but that would be bad practice. Anyway there s more easier band aid fix that i figured out by now. Just change origin of your sprite until you get the results you need.

Comment: [Box2d fixture position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19742486)

Answer (score 1):

Typically the fixtures would approximate the shape of the sprite, they're locked to the body and won't change their transformation. So you just draw the sprite with the body's transformation (position/rotation), and don't care about individual fixtures.

If you really need to draw the fixtures, see the `b2World::DrawDebugData()` method implementation. It uses user-provided `b2Draw` object that would perform actual painting of required primitives.